# BigQuery: filter out hits based on hit and product scope dimensions

Tags: google-bigquery

In BigQuery, there is the Google Analytics based query as is stated below and this works correctly.

```
#standard sql   
SELECT
      Date,
      SUM(totals.visits) AS Sessions,
      SUM(totals.transactions) AS Transactions
    FROM
      `[projectID].[DatasetID].ga_sessions_*`
    WHERE
      _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20181217'
      AND '20181217'
      AND totals.visits > 0
    GROUP BY
      Date
```

In this query, I need to exclude all hits where **within a hit**...

- ..GA custom dimension #23 (hit-scope) contains value 'editor'
  OR
- ..GA custom dimension #6 (product-scope) matches regular expression value '^63.....$' 
  OR
- ..GA hits.page.pagePath matches regular expression value 'gebak|cake'

Note: it is **not** the intention to apply the 3 conditions as stated above on session-level (as in [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6JjcH.png)) but on hit-level, since I'd like to reproduce numbers from another GA view than the view from which the data is loaded to BigQuery. In this other GA view the 3 conditions as are stated above are set as view filters.

The 'best' query thus far is the one below (based on the post of Martin Weitzmann below). However, the dataset is not filtered in this query (in other words, the conditions do not work).

```
SELECT Date, 
-- hits,
SUM(totals.transactions), 
SUM(totals.visits) 

FROM (

(
  SELECT date, totals,
    -- create own hits array
    ARRAY(
      SELECT AS STRUCT 
        hitnumber, 
        page,
        -- create own product array
        ARRAY(
          SELECT AS STRUCT productSku, productQuantity 
          FROM h.product AS p
          WHERE (SELECT COUNT(1)=0 FROM p.customDimensions WHERE index=6 AND value like '63%') 
        ) AS product
      FROM t.hits as h
      WHERE 
        NOT REGEXP_CONTAINS(page.pagePath,r'gebak|cake')
        AND
        (SELECT COUNT(1)=0 FROM h.customDimensions WHERE index=23 AND value like '%editor%')
    ) AS hits
  FROM
    `[projectID].[DatasetID].ga_sessions_*` t
  WHERE 
  _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20181217'
  AND '20181217'
  AND totals.visits > 0
  ))
  GROUP BY Date
```

Does anyone know how to achieve the desired output?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Note: the projectID and datasetID have been masked in both queries because of privacy concerns.

Comment: can't you add those condition in where clause using "REGEXP_EXTRACT" function?

Comment: @MJK, I don't think so, see for my explanation my comment in the post below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Own arrays approach

You can create your own hits and product arrays by using sub-queries on the original and feeding their output back into array functions. In those subqueries you can filter out your hits and products:

```sql
#standardsql
SELECT
  date,
  hits
  --SUM(totals.visits) AS Sessions,
  --SUM(totals.transactions) AS Transactions
FROM
  (
  SELECT 
    date, totals,
    -- create own hits array
    ARRAY(
      SELECT AS STRUCT 
        hitnumber, 
        page,
        -- create own product array
        ARRAY(
          SELECT AS STRUCT productSku, productQuantity 
          FROM h.product AS p
          WHERE (SELECT COUNT(1)=0 FROM p.customDimensions WHERE index=6 AND value like '63%') 
        ) AS product
      FROM t.hits as h
      WHERE 
        NOT REGEXP_CONTAINS(page.pagePath,r'gebak|cake')
        AND
        (SELECT COUNT(1)=0 FROM h.customDimensions WHERE index=23 AND value like '%editor%')
    ) AS hits
  FROM
    `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_20161104` t
  )
--GROUP BY 1
LIMIT 100
```

I left this example in an ungrouped state, but you can easily adjust it by commenting out the `hits` and group accordingly ...

## Segmentation approach

I think you just need the right sub-query in your `WHERE` statement:

```sql
#standardsql
SELECT
  date,
  SUM(totals.visits) AS Sessions,
  SUM(totals.transactions) AS Transactions
FROM
  `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_*` t
WHERE
  (SELECT COUNT(1)=0 FROM t.hits h
    WHERE 
      (SELECT count(1)>0 FROM h.customDimensions WHERE index=23 AND value like '%editor%')
      OR
      (SELECT count(1)>0 from h.product p, p.customdimensions cd WHERE index=6 AND value like '63%')
      OR
      REGEXP_CONTAINS(page.pagePath,r'gebak|cake')
  )
GROUP BY date
```

Since all your groups are on session level, you don't need any flattening (resp. cross joins with arrays) on the main table, which is costly.
In your outermost `WHERE` you enter the `hits` array with a subquery - it's like a for-each on rows. Here you can already count occasions of `REGEXP_CONTAINS(page.pagePath,r'gebak|cake')`.

For the other cases, you write a subquery again to enter the respective array - in the first case, `customDimensions` within `hits`. This is like a nested for-each inside the other one (subquery in a subquery).

In the second case, I'm simply flattening - but within the subquery only: `product` with its `customDimensions`. So this is a one-time nested for-each as well because I was lazy and cross-joined. I could've written another Subquery instead of the cross-join, so basically a triple-nested for-each (subquery in a subquery in a subquery).

Since I'm counting cases that I want to exclude, my outer condition is `COUNT(1)=0`.

I could only test it with ga sample data .. so it's kind of untested. But I guess you get the idea.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this input Martin! However unfortunately the result is not really what I was hoping for.

With the query as you proposed, I reproduced the numbers from the GA interface exactly, but on a segment-basis. But too much data is filtered out now. E.g. suppose that a visitor hits a page where the URL contains 'cake' (this hit should be filtered out), but within the same session later did a transaction where all 3 conditions as stated above pass, I still like the transaction to be included. So actually I'd like the conditions as stated above to apply on hit-basis, not session-basis.

Comment: To clarify further: my goal is actually to reproduce numbers from a GA view which isn't the view which is loaded to BigQuery. The conditions above serve as filters for this view.

Comment: To reproduce the data on session-level (so which is not giving the desired output, see my input in the comment above) I used the following segment, see this screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6JjcH.png

Comment: That would mean the other view is excluding sessions - maybe because sessions only have one pageview? Otherwise I don't see how filtering for hits would affect this at all. Can you try adding `AND hitnumber=1` (just to estimate) to see if it gets closer?

Comment: The other view is not excluding sessions; GA view filters filter out data on hit-level, not on session-level. In the query you provided whole sessions are excluded where in **any hit** within the session one of the 3 conditions did apply (adding the hitnumber=1 didn't work, and I saw in the data that also whole sessions with many hits are excluded, also hits that I would like to have included in the data). But I'd like to only exclude **hits** in which one of the 3 conditions apply. Eg if a session has 40 hits, it could be that 5 hits should be excluded based on the conditions and 35 included.

Comment: Ok, it excludes 5 hits - what effect does that have on transactions and sessions when the filter doesn't affect transactions or bounce sessions with the filtered page? Anyway - see the update.

Comment: Thanks a lot Martin for the feedback and help! I just replied below, because I had to paste the query I tried given your updated input. To answer your question: If one of these 5 hits would be fired on the transaction page (and in this hit is also the ecommerce code included), then this transaction should be excluded. To be more specific with an example, suppose in the transaction hit a product is present with dimension 6 regex value ^63.....$, then the transaction hit including the transaction should be excluded.

Comment: I just added the query I created (based on your query) in the original question of this ticket, however also this query is still without the desired output.

Comment: These are the two approaches - one segmentation for sessions and one building your own arrays before querying. There is not much more to it. Maybe your view filter settings are a bit different - e.g. bot filter on in one and off in the other etc. This is investigation you need to do - I can only help you with queries

Comment: Thanks Martin. Indeed I have to figure it out a bit further to really solve the issue, but I guess I can proceed further with your feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick example/idea on how to use WITH and REGEXP_EXTRACT on a public set

```
WITH CD6 AS (
SELECT cd.value, SUM(totals.visits) AS Sessions6Sum
FROM
  `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_*`,
   UNNEST(hits) AS hits,
   UNNEST(hits.product) AS prod,
   UNNEST(prod.customDimensions) AS cd
   WHERE cd.index=6 
   AND NOT REGEXP_CONTAINS(cd.value,r'^63.....$')
   GROUP BY cd.value
),
CD23 AS (
SELECT cd.value, SUM(totals.visits) AS Sessions23Sum
FROM
  `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_*`,
   UNNEST(hits) AS hits,
   UNNEST(hits.product) AS prod,
   UNNEST(prod.customDimensions) AS cd
   WHERE cd.index=23 
   AND NOT REGEXP_CONTAINS(cd.value,r'editor')
   GROUP BY cd.value
)

select CD6.Sessions6Sum + CD23.Sessions23Sum from CD6, CD23
```

You can get more information on how to use REGEXP_EXTRACT in bigQuery official  [API page](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#regexp_extract)

Comment: The function REGEXP_EXTRACT is known to me, but the whole issue here is - because of the fact a filter on hit and product level custom dimensions is needed - that UNNEST() is required on the hit and product level. But it looks like when I unnest on the product level, hit level custom dimension data cannot be accessed anymore (correct me if I'm wrong here).

Comment: If you can edit your originl sql to better show your problem it will help. What I can suggest for now is to use the WITH sql to create 3 objects with your different filters and than select from them the data you need

Comment: Tamir, in the description section I now added the full query which did not result in the desired output. As you can see, I did several UNNEST() to get access to product and hit level.

Comment: I edit my example based on your SQL. You still need to adapt it to your needs but I hope the direction of it is what you need to solve your problem

Comment: Thanks Tamir for providing the query. This however is not working unfortunately. Because of the UNNESTING() the SUM(totals.visits) is more than 10 times higher than it should be according to what is displayed in the Google Analytics UI. This is probably because in the resulting dataset the records are on hit/product level, but totals.visits are already showing as an aggregate for the session (also for hit/product rows). I'm not so sure how to work around this in the query you provided. This by the way is also a problem in my original query provided above.

Comment: In addition, SUM(totals.visits) as a sum of subqueries CD6 and CD23 is also showing higher numbers because of the fact that sessions can be included in both of the subqueries.