# BigQuery: How to flatten table in materialized view?

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery, looker-studio

Via Google BigQuery, I'd like to visualize some data in Google Data Studio. Because the dataset is quite large in volume and I'd like to maximize the efficiency in data processing, I nested the data first (on both hit- and productlevel) with the following query (which is strongly simplified for illustration purposes) with as input a Google Analytics table (as by default imported from Google Analytics into BigQuery):

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  visitorid, visitNumber, visitId, visitStartTime, date,
  ARRAY(
  SELECT
    AS STRUCT hits.hitNumber, hits.time, hits.hour,
    ARRAY(
    SELECT
      AS STRUCT product.productSKU, product.v2ProductName, product.productVariant
    FROM
      hits.product) AS productInfo
  FROM
    t.hits
  ORDER BY
    hits.hitNumber) AS hitInfo
FROM
  `[projectID].[DatasetID].ga_sessions_*` AS t
WHERE
  _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN FORMAT_DATE("%Y%m%d",DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))
  AND FORMAT_DATE("%Y%m%d",DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))
```

Because I sensed Google Data Studio has issues dealing with nested data (incorrect aggregations), as a proposed solution I read elsewhere to flatten (i.e. unnest) the data in a [materialized view](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/materialized-views-intro) first and connect the flattened data from this materialized view to Google Data Studio.

(Note: I could also have chosen to directly unnest the data in the above query and connect that to Google Data Studio, but I'd like to go for the 'materialized view'-solution because of data efficiency gain.)

Now, my question is: Does anyone know how to convert to an unnested format in the materialized view-query in this specific case? Reading the documentation, UNNEST() is not supported in materialized view, so I'm unsure how to do this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: To flatten a table you need to join with an unnested array (lateral join) - both are not supported by materialized views.

Comment: @MartinWeitzmann, you're exactly the right person to contact! Reason for posting this question was this article you wrote: https://towardsdatascience.com/https-medium-com-martin-weitzmann-bigquery-sql-on-nested-data-cf9589c105f4. Your reaction to a comment on how to use it in visualization tools was to "use 'flat' materialized views that pre-aggregate large nested tables and act as an intermediate step between raw data and a dashboard". I followed your advice to nest, but am struggling now on how to connect to Data Studio the right way (and avoid incorrect aggregation calculations by DS).

Comment: I didn't expect this restriction back then tbh - the feature was quite new and I didn't test it it too much. The thing is that aggregations are necessary as well. What we usually do is write a DML statement that adds rows to a clustered/partitioned table which in turn feeds a dashboard. You just need something that runs this query regularly.

Comment: @MartinWeitzmann, thanks for the feedback. Currently, all the dashboards I manage have as input partitioned tables. However, although I clearly see the performance benefit of nested tables, I don't see the practical advantage of it currently. Because the data should be connected to a dashboard like DS, sooner or later the data should be unnested/flattened again to get it in the format that works the best for DS. Therefore, currently, I don't see why to nest the tables first to unnest it later again. I better can directly unnest the data in a direct query. You agree?

Comment: Yes, it depends on the use case - in my opinion, nested data is better than having multiple tables you need to join first - so it's more about the efficiency of non-aggregated data - for aggregates and things you feed into visualizations, I reckon it's better to have one simple 2d table

Comment: @MartinWeitzmann, clear, thanks! If I would need a table x which serves as a source table for multiple other tables which are meant to connect to dashboard visualization tools such as Data Studio, then I'll definitely create a nested structure for this table x (as you helped me do via https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53904729/bigquery-filter-out-hits-based-on-hit-and-product-scope-dimensions).

Comment: @Timo Rietveld can you share your thoughts and research results, composing the answer that can be so beneficial for the other community contributors?

Comment: @mk_sta, the learnings for me, after the discussion as outlined above: For performance reasons, when a BQ table serves as input for other BQ tables, then it is ideal to create nested tables. When a BQ table serves as input for dashboards, then it is ideal to create unnested tables, because for example Data Studio has aggregation issues when for nested tables.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/materialized-views-intro) discovering BigQuery materialized views  [*Limitations*](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/materialized-views-intro#limitations) chapter:

> A materialized view is limited to referencing only a single table, and
> is not able to use joins or `UNNEST` functionality

Having said this and following the discussion comments being posted by @Timo Rietveld and @Martin Weitzmann I assume that planning to visualize data in Google Data Studio and performing some aggregation functions it would probably required to flatten the data into the simple format using `UNNEST` operator achieving the best result.

For instance, event tables being imported from Google Analytics with multiple key-value parameters represented as an array in event column. You can flatten then each array element as a single row, simplifying data structure as well.

Any further comments or remarks will be highly appreciated, make wiki answer helping other contributors in their research.